# Update fails: mod_fcgid: read data timeout

Tags: updates, timeout

I keep getting the following error when trying to update my craft installation.

```
mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 31 seconds, referer: https://mysite.com/admin/manualupdate/craft
End of script output before headers: index.php, referer: https://mysite.com/admin/manualupdate/craft
```

I have tried updating my `/etc/apache2/mods-available/fcgid.conf` file with:

```
FcgidConnectTimeout 600
FcgidIOTimeout 600
IdleTimeout 600
ProcessLifeTime 600
IPCConnectTimeout 600
BusyTimeout 600
```

And this has given no results. I still get the error. The database wasn't able to go rollback and the site is currently not available. Unfortunately this is happening in production...

Help?

Comment: nginx and php-fpm? I believe php-fpm has its own timeout settings as well.

Comment: I was able to set the `Maximum PHP script run time` to `unlimited` via webmin. I'm assuming this translates to a configuration in the php.ini file. I'll update the post with the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If running Webmin, check the **Website Options** under **Server Configuration** and set `Maximum PHP script run time` to unlimited or a largar value.

This is what finally did the trick but updating `/etc/apache2/mods-available/fcgid.conf` with the following values may have also played a role.

```
FcgidConnectTimeout 600
FcgidIOTimeout 600
IPCCommTimeout 600
```

After these changes and restarting apache, the script was finally able to finish and update the installation successfully.